# Installing MYSQL in an EC2 through user data

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to amazon ec2. I am launching t2.micro instance with ubuntu and in userdata posting a script to  install mysql server and create a schema and user etc. I am doing it this way as I am experimenting with auto scaling.  Trying this script works after instance creation through command prompt. But via userdata mysql is not able connect, shows this error:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Is this because of security groups is not applied yet so no process is allowed to connect that port.

Please let me know

The script looks like this

````
#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/bash

apt update &
process_id=$!
wait $process_id

# Install DB Server
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password password'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password password'
apt-get install mysql-server -y &
process_id=$!
#echo "waiting $(timstamp)" >>  /var/log/script-out 
wait $process_id
#echo "waiting done $(timstamp)" >>  /var/log/script-out 

#wait for installation to complete
sleep 120

# Secure DB Server
mysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''" 1>>/var/log/script-out 2>>/var/log/script-out
#echo "1 done" >> /var/log/script-out 
mysql  --user="root" --password="password" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')"  1>>/var/log/script-out 2>>/var/log/script-out
#echo "2 done" >> /var/log/script-out 
mysql  --user="root" --password="password" -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test"  1>>/var/log/script-out 2>>/var/log/script-out
#echo "3 done" >> /var/log/script-out 
mysql --user="root" --password="password"  -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\\_%'" 1>>/var/log/script-out 2>>/var/log/script-out
#echo "4 done" >> /var/log/script-out 
mysql --user="root" --password="password"  -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"  1>>/var/log/script-out 1>>/var/log/script-out 2>>/var/log/script-out

# Configure OWN Cloud Schema and usermysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "CREATE DATABASE owncloud" 1>>/var/log/script-out 2>>/var/log/script-out
#echo "5 done" >> /var/log/script-out 
mysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "CREATE USER 'owncloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'"
mysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "CREATE USER 'owncloud'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" 
mysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to owncloud@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to owncloud@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql --user="root" --password="password" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"

# Override mysql to user ec2 host private ip
service mysql stop &
process_id=$!
wait $process_id

echo "#Override the mysql server ip address to private ipv4" >> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
echo "bind_address=$(hostname -I)" >> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
service mysql start &
process_id=$!
wait $process_id```
````

Comment: Any reason you can't specify a proper security group at launch time?

Comment: FYI I would not run install tasks in the background, and then wait for them in the foreground. Just remove the ampersand and the wait code. The shell will simply wait for the installation without all that.

Comment: Is it possible to mention the security groups in user data script. Is there any API available

Comment: No. t's done when the instance is launched. How are you launching instance?

Comment: Launching it from the console. The script is added in the user data section when instance is launched

Comment: You need to specify a proper security group from the console. There is a step in the launch sequence for that. Create that Security Group before your next launch, then specified when you do the launch

Comment: Its launched in proper security group only allowin 80 and 3306 from anywhere

Comment: Great. Does it connect now from the command line on the instance?

Comment: Yes it connects from ssh no problems with that